# Copy some values to create another row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1064

It is telling me that there is a syntax error somewhere in this, however each query works individually, it is only when I am trying to combine them that it is not working.

```
INSERT INTO users( username, password , callsign, macroregion, privelages ) 
VALUES ( (SELECT username, password, callsign, macroregion, privelages
            FROM users
           WHERE username =  'someuser'
           LIMIT 1) )
```

I am totally stumped here, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO users( username, password , callsign, macroregion, privelages ) 
SELECT username, password, callsign, macroregion, privelages
  FROM users
 WHERE username =  'someuser'
 LIMIT 1
```

If you want to use a SELECT statement to supply values for an INSERT statement, you omit the `VALUES` clause.  And enclose columns/table names with backticks (`) when they are [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), not all the time.

Comment: @RVward: Yes, you don't need the brackets or `VALUES` clause.  And this is consistent on every database I know of (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc).

Comment: Sorry, guess that was just something I overlooked before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RVward: You mean this answer hasn't actually solved your problem?

Comment: @Andriy M: RVward deleted his first comment, but it was along the lines of not being aware of the correct syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Insert-Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) for this.

```
 INSERT INTO users( username, password , callsign, macroregion, privelages ) 
 SELECT username, password, callsign, macroregion, privelages
       FROM users
       WHERE username =  'someuser'
       LIMIT 1
```